# "TypeError: react.createContext" is not a function with Next.js 13 and Radix UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using a Radix UI select component in Next.js 13 with Typescript and it throws this error: `TypeError: $9g4ps$react.createContext is not a function`

Radix components have worked for me before in other projects, am I doing something wrong here?

The file (literally copy pasted from the template):

```js
import * as Select from '@radix-ui/react-select';

export default () => (

    <Select.Root>

      <Select.Trigger>
        <Select.Value />
        <Select.Icon />
      </Select.Trigger>

      <Select.Portal>

        <Select.Content>
          <Select.ScrollUpButton />
          <Select.Viewport>

            <Select.Item>
              <Select.ItemText />
              <Select.ItemIndicator />
            </Select.Item>

          </Select.Viewport>
          <Select.ScrollDownButton />
        </Select.Content>

      </Select.Portal>
    </Select.Root>
)
```

Comment: Are you using the `app` directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Next.js 13 uses React Server Components by default, which don't support any sort of state.

To use `React.Context`, add the `"use client";` directive at the top of the file.

Comment: I want to clarify something... SSR pre-Next13 allowed for rendering components (even with state) on the server. But post-Next13, server side components (which I assume is different to server-side rendering) cannot render components with state. So in [statements like this](https://www.radix-ui.com/docs/primitives/overview/server-side-rendering) from RadixUI, it can support SSR but NOT server side components (in Next13) right? Essentially SSR is a verb and server side components is a noun. RadixUI supports SSR but all primitives that use state and context cannot be a server side component right?